# Aliasing glm::vec4 in class using union

Tags: c++, unions, glm-math

I want to enhance my AABB class in my raytracer by doing member variable aliasing(make `AABB::min` alias to `AABB::bounds[0]` and `AABB::max` alias to `AABB::bounds[1]`)

This is the current AABB code.

```
class AABB
{
public:
    //methods ignored...

    float4 min;
    float4 max;
};
```

To implement class member aliasing. I tried to use union to achieve it. Which makes the declaration of the variables looks like this.

```
union
{
    float4 bounds[2];
    struct {float4 min,max;};
};
```

But this gives me the following error message:

```
error: member ‘glm::float4 Incarnate::AABB::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::min’ with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate
     struct {float4 min,max;};
```

After searching on Google. I don't find any way to workaround this issue while still achieving my original goal of aliasing the variables. (All solutions I found will add complexity on accessing the variables.)

Is there anyway around this?

Note: `float4` is `glm::vec4`. I used the GLM compatibility header so I could program like how I would in OpenCL.